# Handling concurrency in Ansible Python module

Tags: python, ansible

I have an Ansible module that is capable of creating Influx Db bucket. Works fine when there's only one host in play, but when there are multiple hosts for which the playbook is running in parallel - only one gets the bucket ID, the others don't. Here's module code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
import requests
import re
import json

def bucket_present(data):
    has_changed = False
    has_failed = False
    ssl_verify = True
    bucket_id = 0

    url = data['url'] + '/api/v2/buckets'
    access_token = data['auth_token']
    bucket_name = data['name']
    organization_id = data['org_id']
    description = data['description']
    retention_policy = data['retention_policy']
    if data['selfsigned_ssl'] and data['selfsigned_ssl'] == "yes":
        ssl_verify = False

    headers = {'Authorization': 'Token ' + access_token}

    # Retention policy is in days
    p = re.compile('^[0-9]+d$')
    if p.match(retention_policy):
        retention_policy_s = int(retention_policy.strip('d')) * 86400
    else:
        print(json.dumps({
            "changed": False,
            "failed": True,
            "msg": "Invalid retention policy parameter. Example: 100d"
        }))
        sys.exit(1)

    # Check if the bucket already exists in influxdb
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=ssl_verify)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        has_failed = True
        return has_changed, has_failed, r.json()

    for bucket in r.json()['buckets']:
        if bucket['name'] == bucket_name:
            bucket_id = bucket['id']
            meta = {"present": "Bucket: " + bucket_name + " already exists.", "bucket_id": bucket_id}
            return has_changed, has_failed, meta

    payload = {
        "orgID": organization_id,
        "name": bucket_name,
        "description": description,
        "rp": bucket_name,
        "retentionRules": [
            {
                "type": "expire",
                "everySeconds": retention_policy_s
            }
        ]
    }

    # Create new bucket
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload, verify=ssl_verify)
    if r.status_code != 201:
        if r.json()['code'] == 'conflict':
            meta = {"present": "Bucket: " + bucket_name + " already exists.", "bucket_id": bucket_id}
            has_changed = False
            return has_changed, has_failed, meta
        else:
            has_failed = True
            return has_changed, has_failed, r.json()
    else:
        has_changed = True
        meta = {"created": r.json(), "bucket_id": r.json()['id']}
        return has_changed, has_failed, meta


def bucket_absent(data):
    has_changed = False
    has_failed = False
    found = False
    bucket_id = 0
    ssl_verify = True

    url = data['url'] + '/api/v2/buckets'
    access_token = data['auth_token']
    bucket_name = data['name']
    if data['selfsigned_ssl'] and data['selfsigned_ssl'] == "yes":
        ssl_verify = False

    headers = {'Authorization': 'Token ' + access_token}

    # Check bucket ID and if it exists in database
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=ssl_verify)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        has_failed = True
        return has_changed, has_failed, r.json()

    for bucket in r.json()['buckets']:
        if bucket['name'] == bucket_name:
            found = True
            bucket_id = bucket['id']

    if found:
        r = requests.delete(url + '/' + bucket_id, headers=headers, verify=ssl_verify)
        # REST code for 'bucket does not exist'
        if r.status_code == 404:
            has_changed = False
            meta = {"absent": "Bucket: " + bucket_name + " does not exist in InfluxDB. Skipping..."}
            return has_changed, has_failed, meta
        # REST code for 'bucket successfully deleted'
        elif r.status_code == 204:
            has_changed = True
            meta = {"deleted": "SUCCESS: Bucket " + bucket_name + " deleted.", "bucket_id": bucket_id}
            return has_changed, has_failed, meta
        else:
            meta = {"absent": r.json()}
            has_failed = True
            return has_changed, has_failed, meta
    else:
        has_changed = False
        meta = {"absent": "Bucket: " + bucket_name + " does not exist in InfluxDB. Skipping..."}
        return has_changed, has_failed, meta


def main():
    fields = {
        "url": {"required": True, "type": "str"},
        "auth_token": {"required": True, "type": "str"},
        "org_id": {"default": "example.org", "type": "str"},
        "name": {"required": True, "type": "str"},
        "description": {"required": False, "type": "str"},
        "retention_policy": {"default": "30d", "type": "str"},
        "selfsigned_ssl": {"required": False, "type": "str"},
        "state": {
            "default": "present",
            "choices": ["present", "absent"],
            "type": "str"
        },
    }

    choice_map = {
      "present": bucket_present,
      "absent": bucket_absent,
    }

    module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec=fields)
    has_changed, has_failed, result = choice_map.get(module.params['state'])(module.params)
    module.exit_json(changed=has_changed, failed=has_failed, meta=result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and the module is executed as follows:

```
    - name: Create new bucket for tenant
      influxdb_bucket:
        url: "https://{{ influxdb_host }}:{{ influxdb_port }}"
        auth_token: "{{ influxdb_admin_token }}"
        org_id: "{{ organization_id }}"
        name: "{{ client_bucket }}"
        description: "For client {{ client_bucket }} by Ansible"
        retention_policy: 365d
        state: "{{ state }}"
        selfsigned_ssl: "yes"
      register: bucket
```

What I want to achieve:
3 hosts running the module, one of them is creating buckets, the other two gets the bucket ID. It seems like module sends multiple REST request to Influx DB endpoint and doesn't wait for the response in case of other two hosts. What are my options? Introducing some random sleep command, some advanced Python concurrency/locking mechanisms or some "magic" by Ansible is able to solve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ansible runs your module on each target in parallel and totally independently. You are taking this the wrong way IMO. You don't need to run this on each remote target. You can actually `delegate_to: localhost`. You should also `run_once: true`. This will create/check the bucket exists only once in your play and the registered var will be assigned to each hosts in play with the same values (i.e. the created/existing bucket ID)

Comment: Yes, you're completely right on that point. I already got `delegate_to: localhost` but missed that `run_once: true` part, probably an oversight. Thanks for saving me further investigation time. Obviously now it works as intended.